# A better way to work with 6 bit chunks

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift2

#### A more elegant way to do this?

I'm wondering if there is some way to use the functional programing aspects of swift to chunk an array into **6-bit chunks**

What I have works but it just doesn't *feel* like its the best way to do things

### PseudoCode

I figured there is 4 types masking possible

```
[1111 1122]  [2222 3333]  [3344 4444]
```

- first 6 bits
- last 2 bits and first 4 bits of next byte
- last 4 bits and first 2 bits of next byte
- last 6 bits

I've put together some code that basically iterates through the bytes, calculates which "type" of masking we are doing - and masks appropriately.  It just feels somewhat rough - perhaps there is a way to use some of the functional commands like `map` to break the byte structure into **6-bit chunks**.

### Step 1 - Convert into a byte array

The first thing i do is take my `NSData` and break it up into an array of `UInt8`

```
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(rawNSData.bytes)
let bytes = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: rawNSData.length)
```

### Step 2 -

Next I wrote this parser which basically tracks what "byte" we are on and which "type" of masking we need to perform (see above).

```
func parseDLAC(data : NSData, startingByte startingDataLocation : Int) -> String {

    var ret = "";

    ///Tracks the current "decoding" - so that we can figure out which type of masking to do
    var currentDLACNumber = 0

    while (true) {

        // 4 types of masking possible
        let maskIteration = currentDLACNumber % 4

        ///Where to start the current decoding
        let startingByte = (currentDLACNumber * 6) / 8 + startingDataLocation
        let endingByte   = ((currentDLACNumber + 1 ) * 6) / 8 + startingDataLocation

        if (endingByte > data.length) {
            return "ERROR";
        }

        var rawValue : UInt8

        switch(maskIteration) {

        case 0:  // grab 1st 6 bits and shift right
            rawValue = (bytes[startingByte] & 0xFC) >> 2
        case 1:  // 2 & 4
            rawValue = ((bytes[startingByte] & 0x03) << 4) | ((bytes[startingByte+1] & 0xF0) >> 4)
        case 2:
            rawValue = ((bytes[startingByte] & 0x0F ) << 2) | ((bytes[startingByte+1] & 0xC0) >> 6)
        case 3:
            rawValue = (bytes[startingByte] & 0x3F)
        default:
            rawValue = 0
        }

        if (rawValue == 0) {
            return ret
        }

        ret += decodeDLAC(rawValue);


        // Next!
        currentDLACNumber++
    }
    return ret;
}
```

#### Solution

I would love to know if there is a more elegant way to re-write this code.

Given NSData and a starting address (byte offset) is there a way to create an array of 6-bit chunks (UInt8's).  I'm confused about `map` because I know it "tries" to work with distinct array elements.  I also didn't know if there was an `UnsafeMutalbeBitPointer` type that perhaps could help.

Thanks for any help - and yes - **not possible** is a valid answer.

Comment: Just an idea, but Base64 encoding maps 6 bits to each character except, if there is not an even multiple of 6 bits, to the last character.  Could you encode to that and then Base64 decode letter by letter as you need the bits back?  Depends on your application I suppose.

Comment: I'm actually decoding the 6 bits into ASCII using a different format called DLAC

Comment: Ah, got you.  Then my Base64 idea would not be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be easy to do using functional elements of the language, but you can simplify things a lot by processing your data three bytes at a time. This way you can hard-code the application of the four masks, and avoid the `switch` statement altogether.

First, make sure that the number of bytes in `[bytes]` is divisible by three. You can do this by "topping off" the array with one or two zeros after extracting the bytes from raw data.

After that you can do this:

```
for var i = startingDataLocation  ; i+2 < bytes.length ; i += 3 {
    ret += decodeDLAC((bytes[i] & 0xFC) >> 2)
    ret += decodeDLAC(((bytes[i] & 0x03) << 4) | ((bytes[i+1] & 0xF0) >> 4))
    ret += decodeDLAC(((bytes[i+1] & 0x0F ) << 2) | ((bytes[i+2] & 0xC0) >> 6))
    ret += decodeDLAC((bytes[i+2] & 0x3F))
}
```

**P.S.** This solution is based on Dijkstra's story called [*"A Parable"*](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/ewd594.html).

Comment: Well it definitely looks cleaner! :)

Comment: @Jeef Depending on the size of the data being processed, you may need to "undo" the topping off, i.e. removing one, two, or three characters off the end if the original size wasn't divisible by three. I am not familiar with DLAC format, so I am not sure how the format handles "odd sizes".